# MacBook HDD in PC

Tags: macos, windows-7

Well, I screwed up big time today. The long and the short of it is that I spilled water on my MacBook Pro and the motherboard is shot. However, the hard drive seems to be okay. So I plugged the SATA cable into my PC, win 7 32bit, however I cannot find the drive. I just wanna copy some stuff over. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It probably can't read that file system.  Maybe boot off a Linux CD?  Or, do you have a friend with another Mac?

Comment: @MikeChristensen are there any options like a SATA > USB cable? Or any software that can help

Comment: Its not hardware. Its the way the bytes are arranged on the platters of the disk. Mac stores things one way. Windows another. (To simplify a bit.) Perhaps you have a friend with a similar Mac that will let you add your drive to their machine temporarily. It would be nice if you could write protect your drive.

Comment: @AngusFisher - Unsure.  I've never tried reading a Mac drive on a PC.

Comment: So @LeeMeador I'm screwed? I mean I can see if a friend is willing to let me do that, but most likely not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download a driver for windows to view the mac file system... search for an HFS+ driver
Even better, goto an Apple Support community :-)

One example:
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1368010
http://www.markc.me.uk/blog/files/HFSOnWindows.html

there are plenty of others. I used one at home for winXP to write to hfs+